# UIActivityIndicator inside custom UICollectionViewCell - only displays/animate in first cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm animating an ActivityIndicator after a user presses a button in my collection cell, while I wait on a network response.  The code below is called by every instance of the custom cell (confirmed in debugger), but the activity indicator only displays when a button is clicked in the first cell, or when clicked in a cell reusing the first cell.  It doesn't matter if I click the buttons in another cell before the first.

```
customCollectionViewCell.m
@interface customCollectionViewCell(){
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@implementation cutomCollectionViewCell
 - (void) choiceClicked:(id)sender{

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        actvityIndicator.center = self.center;
        [self.contentView addSubview:activityIndicator];
        [actvityIndicator startAnimating];
    });
    async - network stuff
}
```

I'm making sure in prepare for reuse that I'm removing the indicator from superview and setting to nil.

I've also tried only creating the indicator if it doesn't exist and starting animation - still no change in behavior.
edit: Also doesn't matter if just the animating is called from main thread and other calls are explicitly part of the default queue.

```
if (activityIndicator == nil){
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.center = self.center;
    [self.contentView addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
});
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    network call
        });
```

Comment: Does your network call still get called, or does it return instantly or something, for the other cells? When do you stop animating the activity indicator? Why not have an indicator present all the time and use `hidesWhenStopped`?

Comment: Also, while in the debugger, log out some frames and subviews and so forth. If the code is getting executed, that indicator is going _somewhere_.

Comment: Logging out the frames and subviews showed that self.center was returning a CGPoint with the Y value = position in the scrollview, not the center of the cell's height/width.  This makes the activity indicator work in all cells:

`activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);`

Answer (score 8):

Self.center from within the custom cell was returning a CGPoint with a Y value = position in the scrollview, not the center of the cell's height, which placed the activityview well outside the cell's visible frame.

This makes the activity indicator work in all cells: 
`activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);`

Comment: `self.contentView.center` would also have worked. `center` always returns coordinates in the superview's coordinate space.

Comment: Really helpful, +1 In mine case simply passing center of cell to activityindicator center.@minerat